# How to open a new tab with a post request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

Using javascript/jquery, I want to open a new tab. I have this code:

```
window.open("../scripts/map.php", '_blank');
```

which does it, but I also want to attach a huge json string as a parameter. I don't want to attach it to the url. Is there a way to make a jquery ajax call, and have the returned html string, set in the new tab?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck? How is this related to PHP, jQuery, or HTML?

Answer (score 15):

You could define a (possibly hidden) form element, give it the action of the url you want to post to, the method "post", and a target of "_blank", set the json to one of its input fields, the submit the form with jquery using $(form).submit (). You can even use jquery to create and remove the form at runtime.

The target attribute for forms works the same as for hyperlinks.

Comment: Well several hours of struggling with creating a new window not working in IE to have this really simple solution is somewhat frustrating... Thank you for saving my sanity